# How to display List<List<String>> in Visual force page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

In controller I will get the data as `List<List<String>>`. How can I display it on Visual force page?

And that `List<List<String>>` is populated based on user input(Checkbox values).

If it's just `List<String>` then I could able to display them using `datalist`

```
List<String> alist;
```

then I can use this to display them

```
<apex:dataList value="{!alist}" var="c">
    {!c}                        
</apex:dataList>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a list of list "List < List < String>>" you will need to do something like :

```
<apex:repeat value="{!alist}" var="l">
    <apex:dataList value="{!l}" var="c">
          {!c}
    </apex:dataList>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: I am getting this 
Error: Literal value is required for attribute var in <apex:dataList>
for var="{!c}"

Comment: This should read
    <apex:dataList value="{!l}" var="c">

Answer (score 1):

You can show list of list by any below approach

```
1) first approach

    <apex:repeat value="{!ListOfList}" var="List">
     <apex:repeat value="{!list}" var="item">
      {!item}
     </apex:repeat>
    </apex:repeat>

2) Second approach
     (this approach use when we are creating many tables on layout 
    <apex:repeat  value="{!ListOfList}" var="List">
     <apex:pageblocktable value="{!list}" var="item">
      {!item}
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
     </apex:repeat>
```